# Version of useMemo for caching a value that will never change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an expensive computation function that useMemo is perfect for. The thing is, I know the arguments for this computation function will never change. As I understand it, useMemo forces you to include the arguments within an Array for its second argument in order to check and see if they have changed so that the memoized value can be recalculated.
ex)

```
useMemo( ()=> expensiveFunction(arg1, arg1, arg3), [arg1, arg2, arg3])
```

But this is very messy and unneeded to me since I know arg1, 2, and 3 will never change for my situation. Is there some way to just indicate this to the useMemo function so that I can just skip the second argument altogether? If I have a lot of arguments, it's messy to rewrite them all again in an array when I know from the start none of them will change. This is strictly for code neatness, it's not the end of the world if this is not possible, but I was curious is something like this exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for react hooks that is equivalent to a class-based `componentDidMount` is to use an empty dependency array.

```
useMemo( ()=> expensiveFunction(arg1, arg1, arg3), []);
```

**But** according to [this FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations) topic about memoizing values, particularly this blurb:

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.**
>   In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized
>   values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for
>   offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without
>   useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance. (For rare cases
>   when a value must never be recomputed, you can lazily initialize a
>   ref.)

[Lazily initialize a value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily)

useState initialization function

```
// expensiveFunction() is only called once
const [value] = useState(() => expensiveFunction(arg1, arg1, arg3));
```

useRef

```
const ref = useRef(null);

// expensiveFunction value is created lazily once
function getExpensiveValue() {
  if (ref.current === null) {
    ref.current = expensiveFunction(arg1, arg1, arg3);
  }
  return ref.current;
}

// When you need it, call getExpensiveValue()
// ...
```

Between these two the first is simpler and easier to read and reason about and the one I'd recommend.

Comment: Thank you, the useState example accomplishes what I want more cleanly. useMemo works too, but I get an error unless my array has the same number of arguments as my function. So I would use dummy values like [0,0,0] for three arguments. Still, the useState example is more clean. This whole pattern is still somewhat troubling though. It's kind of a hack and syntactically misleading to use the useState hook for something that isn't actually state and doesn't change. I hope the React crew makes something cleaner in the future for this case.